# How can one decipher the IANA port registration form?

Tags: networking, network-programming, tcp

I have created a simple Twisted based TCP server and Android client. I have used my own protocol for this purpose. While I have tried to lay out my protocol in a way which seems logical, this is the first protocol that I have written, so I doubt it conforms to any standards for a TCP protocol, if such norms even exist. However, I did design it so that I could easily add features without breaking backwards compatibility with older versions of the protocol.

To avoid a potential port conflict, I would like to register a port with IANA. I found the registration form [here](http://www.iana.org/cgi-bin/usr-port-number.pl). However, the questions seem to be highly technical, and I only have a basic knowledge of protocols. So, my question is this: Can anyone describe what these questions are asking? And, how one would answer them in general? If possible, please also include how the general answers would relate to [my protocol](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/560015/Protocol.txt). That way, anyone else who has a similar question can see both types of answers.

Thanks,
Sean W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't wish to be unkind but unless you can answer those simple questions you really aren't ready to register a port number request with IANA. Are you sure you need to? Couldn't you get away with configuration of the server and client? or a naming service?

Comment: I suppose you are right. However, I don't want to use dynamic ports because of the (rather small, I admit) chance of a conflict. However, surly there are resources where I can acquire the knowledge I would need to answer those questions? Can you update your answer with some resources to point me in the right direction? It would be a useful thing to learn if I want to write more complex applications anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, now that I think more carefully about it. I only need the definitions of message formats, message types, and op codes. I know how to fill out the rest of the form.